# How to make regex that accepts string which contains 0-9 minimum 2 times and might contain "%" & "*" and character can be in any position?

Tags: regex

### Eg of Strings

**Valid**

1. `12`
2. `%23`
3. `78%`
4. `12***3`
5. `*1*7`

**Invalid**

1. `8`
2. `*7`
3. `6%`
4. `AB`
5. `%4*`

I have tried many regexes but none of them worked for all cases.

The most closet result found for the regex was `^([*%]*[0-9]{2,}[*%\d]*)$`.

If anyone can help me build this regex it would be helpful. Thank you so much :)

Comment: your regex works perfect, what more do u want?

Comment: @GhostOps No it doesn't. It won't match `*1*7`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^(?:[*%]*\d){2}[*%\d]*$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/auuLkY/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[*%]*\d){2}` - two occurrences of zero or more `*` or `%` chars followed with a digit
- `[*%\d]*` - zero or more digit, `*` or `%` chars
- `$` - end of string.

See a JavaScript demo below:

```js
const texts = ['12','%23','78%','12***3','*1*7', '8','*7','6%','AB','%4*'];
const re = /^(?:[*%]*\d){2}[*%\d]*$/;
for (const text of texts) { 
  console.log(text, '->', re.test(text));
}
```